# Why is my character string distance always 5?

Tags: java, string, character, hamming-distance

I have a project that has three requirements:

1. Prompt user to enter 5 uppercase characters and save as
   variable.
2. Randomly generate a 5 character string and save as variable.
3. Compute the distance between the two strings.

   I thought I had it and it looked like it worked, but then I noticed that the computed distance between the two strings is always 5.
   I am guessing that my `stringLength` is somehow being used for `stringDist`.

   If you could look it over and lead me in the right direction as to what I'm missing, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println ("Please enter 5 Uppercase letters.");
        String userString = scan.nextLine();
        
        int leftLimit = 48; // numeral '0'
        int rightLimit = 122; // letter 'z'
        int stringLength = 5;
        Random random = new Random();
     
        String randString = random.ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1)
          .filter(i -> (i <= 57 || i >= 65) && (i <= 90 || i >= 97))
          .limit(stringLength)
          .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
          .toString();
        { 
            int i = 0, stringDist = 0; 
            while (i < userString.length()) 
            { 
                if (userString.charAt(i) != randString.charAt(i)) 
                    stringDist++; 
                    i++; 
            } 
             System.out.println ("The user string is: " + userString);
             System.out.println ("The random string is: " + randString);
             System.out.println ("The distance between " + userString + " and " + randString + " is " + stringDist);
}
```

Comment: What is the distance, the difference between each character of the String?

Comment: Well, you increase `strintDist` by 1 for every different character, so if all the characters are different, you end up with `stringDist == userString.length()`.  What did you expect?

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant. In your case, just a few lines with hardcoded Strings would do it.

Comment: I was expecting the total ASCII distance between the two strings but you are right Kevin Anderson  I chose the wrong code for step 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're comparing a five character user-entered string with a randomly generated string, there's a good chance that there no positions where the corresponding characters are the same, which would make the distance equal to five. So in that sense, there's nothing wrong with your code. If you repeatedly run the program, you'll eventually get a distance less than five.

Comment: Thank you.  You and Kevin Anderson have made me aware that I have chosen the wrong code for step 3.  What I need is a way to compute the ASCII distance between each character in the code and then add them together.